# fscanf reading and saving

Tags: c, file

I have zero knowledge about using files in C and I'm trying to read a file with this data

```
050     1100               
051     5100

100     0005
```

and save the numbers into constants like this:

```
PC   cod  IR      
\/   \/   \/
```

050 ---     1  ----  200
051 ---     5  ----   100

```
   Mem[PC]
    \/
```

100   -  0005

The problem is that I don't know how to do it. I only have this code I read from a book that reads my file and save the first data to a char buffer, or at least that's what I think it does, but it doesn't continue with the rest of the data.

```c
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;    
    char buffer[100];

    fp = fopen("prueba.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer);
    printf("%s", buffer);    
    fclose(fp);    

    return 0;    
 }
```

and this is the content of `prueba.txt`:

```
050     1100               
051     5100

100     0005
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

First off, forget you ever heard of `fscanf`.  It is far more trouble than it is worth.

Second off, I don't know what you mean by "save the numbers into constants", but *in general*, the right way to do this sort of thing in C is to read line by line with [`fgets`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fgets.3.html) (or [`getline`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getline.3.html) if you have it) and then extract individual numbers from the line using [`strsep`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strsep.3.html) and [`strtoul`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtoul.3.html).

Third off, stylistically speaking, there is only one thing worse than putting spaces on the inside of your parentheses, and that is *inconsistently* putting spaces inside and/or around parentheses and commas.  You will give the next person who has to read this code a headache.

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing right now is only reading one word, you are using the fscanf to read and the %s to read the first string it sees.

If you want to read all of the words in the file you must loop over them like this:

```
while(feof(fp)==0){

fscanf(fp,"%s",buffer);
*** Do what every action you want to do with your buffer here ***
}
```

Comment: `while(!feof(fp)) { read; process; }` is an antipattern, because `feof` only becomes true when you *try to read past the end of the file*, not when you merely *reach* the end of the file.  So you'll get a failed read operation that the code is not prepared to deal with.